# Any way to list all global (window) variables that are user-added?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer Tools, in the console, if I type `window` and hit enter, I get a long list of global variables that are properties of the window object. Is there any way to filter this down to those that are added by the user and not already built into the window object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// setTimeout is needed and is being used here just if the property adding and the checking will be done in sequence. To avoid getting the same reference values on the current time lapse. Check the answer code

// Get current window Properties;
var windowInitProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

setTimeout(() => window.newProperty = 'newProperty', 0)

setTimeout(() => {
    // List new Properties;
    console.log(
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(property => {
            return windowInitProperties.indexOf(property) < 0;
        })
    );
}, 0)
```

```
// Get current window Properties;
var windowInitProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);


// New property added to window
var newProperty = 'newProperty';

// List new Properties;
console.log(
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(property => {
        return windowInitProperties.indexOf(property) < 0;
    })
);
```

Mind that `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.keys` is needed to get even the properties that are `enumerable: false`.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding your global variable cache the core/predefined variable names. After adding your new global variable - you can compare the new list with old one and print the new global variables.

```
var predefined_variables = Object.keys(window);

window.newone = 'test';
window.xyz = 'testXYZ';

var new_variables = Object.keys(window).filter(function(key){
    return predefined_variables.indexOf(key)<0;
});

console.log(new_variables);
//["newone", "xyz"]
```

Comment: Nice - yeah that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, and even if it's was possible.it's a bad practise.
Instead, you can create a namespace on window object like following:

window.myApp=window.myApp || {};

myApp.variable1=value1;
...
myApp.variableN=valueN;

Comment: I don't disagree with you. I'm working in a legacy app, and keep seeing stray global variables they've defined, so I was curious to get a list to see just how many they've created.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the chrome team builds something in for this particular case, then the answer is no.

The window is simply an object. The properties added doesnt keep any information or metadata about who added it, when, etc.

If you want (and probably should), prefix properties you're adding to the window. This will prevent collisions with other libraries making use of window, and then you could write a simple for-in loop to grab only the properties/values that use your prefix.